# Why isn't my 'type' attribute being "seen"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm a backend guy, our frontend guy just left, and though I "think" i fixed the issue, I'd like to understand what was going on.

So I got this error, from a script `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` - in Chromium 39.0.2171.65

The browser showed me this line that was causing the issue: `if (type.indexOf('select') == 0)`, from which i understood that `type` was undefined.

So what's `type`?

```
$('form :input[type!=hidden][type!=submit]').each(function() {
 ...
 var type = $(this).attr('type');
 ...
}
```

I debugged my element, turns out there's 16 of them.

When for each one of them I run this `$(this).attr('type')` statement, i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, and `$(this).type` returns `undefined`, although `this.type` IS defined and has a proper value, and if I use that line, everything seems to be working as expected.

The problem might have been caused by an upgrade in jQuery-ui, from 1.8 to 1.11, but I don't really know, and neither does this http://api.jquery.com/attr/ site make it clear.

So I'd like to know, if possible, how this might have worked, and if the fix I used is ok enough, or whether I should do something else.

Comment: Change `$(this).attr('type')` to `$(this).prop('type')`.

Comment: Is it possible that some of your input doesn't have a type set?

Comment: `this.type` is the most appropriate way to check input type, really no need to use any jQuery object here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suchit's answer is correct.  However, to answer your question as to WHY this is happening, why it had previously worked, etc... that requires some explanation.

There is a difference between a property and an attribute in javascript.  sometimes there are both attributes and properties, but sometimes not.  For example, for a input element where you have `type="text"` there is both an attribute called type, and a property called type.

In this case, however, you seem to be looking for a select element, which does not have a "type" attribute, but would have a type property.

Prior to jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method of jQuery would return both type and properties in certain cases.  This was deprecated in 1.6, though it may have still worked.  My guess is that at some point in time (perhaps after jQuery 1.8) the actual functionality was removed, having been deprecated since jQuery 1.6.

It does appear that there were changes made in jQuery 1.9 around this area.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

EDIT:

Upon further investigation, I can't see how this would have worked in jQuery 1.8 at all.  The behavior was changed in 1.6, and was not allowed to continue to work as I had first suspected.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate this.  You can run both of them, by changing the commenting to include the correct version, and you can see the difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/3104wcbp/

Is it possible the html was changed to add the select statements where they were previously input statements?

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
$(this).prop('type');
```

demo here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body >
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('form :input[type!=hidden][type!=submit]').each(function() {
         var type = $(this).prop('type');
         console.log(type);
        });
 });
   </script>
   <form>
<input type='text' name ="name"value="something1">
<input type='radio'name ="r" value="something2">


</form>
```

**NOTE:**  var type = this.type; will also work.

Comment: This would be more appropriate example `<input name ="r" value="something1">`, using default input type (which is `text`)